# Change stem length for Drum Beams in Musixtex

Tags: musixtex

When try to change the stem lenght using the command stemlength, it seems it doesn't work for Drum Beams...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\begin{document}


\begin{music}
    \largemusicsize
    \setlines{1}{0}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nobarnumbers
    \nostartrule
    \startextract
    {\Huge{\ding{200}}}$\quad$
    \stemlength{6.4}
    \Notes\zcharnote{-14}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} L}\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} R}\zcn{i}{\hspace*{0.15cm}$7$}\stemlength{6.4}\ibu0a0\islurd0a\trrmu a\qbp0a\roff{\tbbu0\tbu0\tslur0a\usf f\zcharnote{-14}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} R}\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} L}\qb0a} \en 
    \Notes\zcharnote{-14}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} L}\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} R}\zcn{i}{\hspace*{0.15cm}$7$}\stemlength{6.4}\ibu0a0\islurd0a\trrmu a\qbp0a\roff{\tbbu0\tbu0\tslur0a\usf f\zcharnote{-14}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} R}\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} L}\qb0a} \en 
    \stemlength{\DefaultStemlength}
    \zendextract
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Expected output:
[image: expected output]

Comment: Without proof, try adjusting your note level to at least d, not a. Perhaps that's all you need to do. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667945/245790 for reference.

Comment: Suppose that we use real notes (not percussion), in that scenario we can not move the note to d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in my answer regarding the DDT: with beams you determine the length of the stem manually, so write:

```
\ibu0c0\islurd0a\trrmu b
```

by which you tell Musixtex to start the beam as if the note head would be on c (instead of a) and raise the tremolo half of the distance, i.e. place it on b instead of a. Of course you need to adapt the hight of the number and the accent.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\begin{document}


\begin{music}
    \resetlyrics
    \largemusicsize
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
    \setlyrics{R}{R L R L}% added for hand indication
    \setlyrics{L}{L R L R}% added for hand indication
    \setsongraise1{-6mm}
    \setlines{1}{0}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nobarnumbers
    \nostartrule
    \startextract
    \A\assignlyrics1{R,L}% added to place handindication
    \Notes\charnote f{\Huge{\ding{200}}}\sk\en%$\quad$ lifted the number, \sk is the music way to skip one noteskip
    \Notes\zcn{k}{\hspace*{0.28cm}$7$}
    \ibu0c0\islurd0a\trrmu a\qbp0a\roff{\tbbu0\tbu0\tslur0a\usf g\qb0a}\en 
    \Notes\zcn{k}{\hspace*{0.28cm}$7$}
    \ibu0c0\islurd0a\trrmu a\qbp0a\roff{\tbbu0\tbu0\tslur0a\usf g\qb0a}\en 
    \zendextract
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

Solved output:
[image: solved]