# Musixtex grace note vertical size adjustment for Flam Rudiment

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to adjust the grace note vertical size for Flam Rudiment, the code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\begin{document}
        
\begin{music}
        \largemusicsize
        \setlines{1}{0}
        \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
        \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule
        \startextract
        {\Huge{\textcircled{\large 20}}}$\quad$
        \NOtes\smallnotesize\islurd0a\zcharnote{-11}{\textbf\scriptsize \hspace*{-0.08cm} L}\grcu a\en
        \notes \tslur0a\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} R}\qu a \en
        \NOtes\smallnotesize\islurd0a\zcharnote{-11}{\textbf\scriptsize \hspace*{-0.08cm} R}\grcu a\en
        \notes \tslur0a\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} L}\qu a \en
        \zendextract
\end{music}  
    
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The desired output is as follow:
[image: desired output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution just need the stdstemfalse command as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\begin{document}

{\sffamily\bfseries
\begin{music}
        \largemusicsize
        \setlines{1}{0}
        \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
        \def\snotes{\vnotes2.3\elemskip}
        \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule
        \startextract
        {\Huge{\textcircled{\large 20}}}$\quad$
        \snotes\tinynotesize\islurd0a\zcharnote{-11}{\hspace*{-0.08cm} \footnotesize\textbf L}\grcu{d}\en
        \notes \tslur0a\zcharnote{-10}{\hspace*{-0.08cm} \textbf\small R}\qu d \en
        \snotes\stdstemfalse\tinynotesize\islurd0a\zcharnote{-11}{\hspace*{-0.08cm} \footnotesize\textbf R}\grcu a\en
        \notes \tslur0a\zcharnote{-10}{\hspace*{-0.08cm} \textbf\small L}\qu a \en
        \zendextract
\end{music}  
}

\end{document}
```

The output is as follow:
[image: solution]

Comment: Nice. // Because it's not that easy to find, can you please indicate the change in your code? Thanks

Comment: The change is as follow: 1) Define a custom note group for grace notes using \def\snotes{\vnotes2.3\elemskip}, 2) When use note that require additional lines, just include the command  \stdstemfalse inside the note group to disable the preconfigured length stem. That´s all.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the note level for the grace note has to `start at d`, minimum, not a.

Please have a look at the code below. In the preamble I skipped all parts, which are unecessary and potentially distracting here; the article document just gives a more nicer print-out.

[image: results]

```
%\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex} 

\begin{document}

\section{Locating the problems}

\begin{itemize}
  \item removed unecessary parts
  \item used normal staff to see impacts
  \item copied code from page 101
  \item !! note has to be at least \emph{d} !!
\end{itemize}

\begin{music}
        %\instrumentnumber{1}% not needed
        \largemusicsize
       %\setlines{1}{0}% removed, to better see the effect
        \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
        \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule
        \startextract
        % copy from page 101: does it work at all?
        \NOTes\hu h\en
        \notes\multnoteskip\smallvalue\smallnotesize\grcu d\en% !! needs to be at least d !!
        \NOTes\hu i\en
        \bar
        {\Huge{\textcircled{\large 20}}}$\quad$
         \NOtes\multnoteskip\smallvalue\smallnotesize\grcu a\en
         \notes\qu a \en
         \NOtes\multnoteskip\smallvalue\smallnotesize\grcu d\en
         \notes\qu d \en
%        \NOtes\smallnotesize\islurd0a\zcharnote{-11}{\textbf\scriptsize \hspace*{-0.08cm} L}\grcu a\en
%        \notes \tslur0a\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} R}\qu a \en
%        \NOtes\smallnotesize\islurd0a\zcharnote{-11}{\textbf\scriptsize \hspace*{-0.08cm} R}\grcu a\en
%        \notes \tslur0a\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} L}\qu a \en
        \zendextract
\end{music} 

\section{Adjusting to note level d}
\begin{music}
        \largemusicsize
        \setlines{1}{0}
        \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
        \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule
        \startextract
        {\Huge{\textcircled{\large 20}}}$\quad$
        \NOtes\smallnotesize\islurd0a\zcharnote{-11}{\textbf\scriptsize \hspace*{-0.08cm} L}\grcu d\en
        \notes \tslur0a\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} R}\qu d \en
        \NOtes\smallnotesize\islurd0a\zcharnote{-11}{\textbf\scriptsize \hspace*{-0.08cm} R}\grcu d\en
        \notes \tslur0a\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} L}\qu d \en
        \zendextract
\end{music} 

\section{Original code}
% original code        
\begin{music}
        \largemusicsize
        \setlines{1}{0}
        \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
        \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule
        \startextract
        {\Huge{\textcircled{\large 20}}}$\quad$
        \NOtes\smallnotesize\islurd0a\zcharnote{-11}{\textbf\scriptsize \hspace*{-0.08cm} L}\grcu a\en
        \notes \tslur0a\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} R}\qu a \en
        \NOtes\smallnotesize\islurd0a\zcharnote{-11}{\textbf\scriptsize \hspace*{-0.08cm} R}\grcu a\en
        \notes \tslur0a\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} L}\qu a \en
        \zendextract
\end{music}  
    
\end{document}
```